# Текст под картинкой CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, текст

Возник такой вопрос: есть блок, где располагается четыре блока в них картинка и под каждой картинкой текст. Текст плавает из-за того, что картинки немного разные по размеру. Как можно это решить? Обернуть картинку в еще один блок и задать размеры? Или есть более элегантный способ решить данную проблему?

```
<div class="us_flex-container">
        <div class="us_flex-div"><img src="img/direction/service1-png.png" alt="placeholder+image" class="service">
            <h3 class="ustext">ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="us_flex-div"><img src="img/direction/service2-png.png" alt="placeholder+image" class="service">
            <h3 class="ustext">ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="us_flex-div"><img src="img/direction/service3-png.png" alt="placeholder+image" class="service">
            <h3 class="ustext">ТекстТекстТекстТекст</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="us_flex-div"><img src="img/direction/service4-png.png" alt="placeholder+image" class="service">
            <h3 class="ustext">ТекстТекстТекстТекстТекст</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Пример верстки]

По повоуду стилей, то исользовал flex-ы.

Comment: > "Обернуть картинку в еще один блок и задать размеры? ", да оптимальнее будет так

Comment: а можно выложить css ваш?

Answer (score 1):

Можно задать картинкам фиксированную высоту, и задать свойство object-fit

```
img.service {
   height: 250px;
   width: 100%;
   object-fit: contain; 
}
```

P.S. Старайтесь не использовать в верстке заголовков h вообще. У SEO насчет них обычно свои планы, и расставлять их они будут сами.